# Adding a rule which is recurring every 10 people - JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement

I need to be able turn this rule into a piece of code:

**1 free adult chaperone place for every group of 10 children, for    example:**

- **less than 10 children, all adults must pay**
- **between 10 and 19 children: up to 1 free adult**
- **between 20 and 29 children: up to 2 free adults**

**and so on**

Is there a simpler way to do this without having to set a new IF statement which is physically impossible.

```
    final double ADULT_PRICE = 10.5;
    final double CHILD_PRICE = 7.3;
    final double CONCESSION_PRICE = 8.4;
    final double P_P = 2.34;

    //Getting user inputs
    System.out.print("\nEnter the number of adults: ");
    int adultAmount = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("\nEnter the number of children: ");
    int childrenAmount = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("\nEnter the number of concessions: ");
    int concessionAmount = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("\nPostage is £2.34 extra. Press Y accept, press N to decline: ");
    String postageChoice = input.nextLine();

    double total = adultAmount*ADULT_PRICE + childrenAmount*CHILD_PRICE + concessionAmount*CONCESSION_PRICE;
```

I was thinking that every 10 users, you subtract the price of one adult from the total cost of the purchase.

Help would be great, thank you!

Comment: `(adultAmount - (childrenAmount / 10)) * ADULT_PRICE `

Comment: Hint: integer division drops fractions.  So 1 / 10 = 0, 9 / 10 = 0, 10 / 10 = 1, etc.  Try out a few values, I think this is the connection your instructed expected you to make.